# Read text file with delimiter

Tags: vb.net

i want to read text file and from the fifth line take only the first column before (;) this my code to browse and read text :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim OpenFile As New OpenFileDialog
        OpenFile.FileName = ""
        OpenFile.Filter = "Fichier Texte (*.pnp)|*.pnp"
        OpenFile.ShowDialog()
        Try
            Dim lire As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName)
            RichTextBox1.Text = lire.ReadToEnd
            lire.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

help me please

Comment: What is a `pnp` file?  Is it semicolon delimited?

Comment: no it's an extension like txt

Comment: the code of semicolon delimited is not include

Comment: i hope you have solution to my problem

Comment: Please add a relevant sample of your file to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    Dim lineYouWantToRead As Int32 = 5
    Dim fieldYouWantToRead As Int32 = 1
    Dim capturedValue As String = ""

    Using fileReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(OpenFile.FileName)
        fileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        fileReader.SetDelimiters(";")
        While fileReader.LineNumber <= lineYouWantToRead - 1
            Dim currentLine As String() = fileReader.ReadFields()
            capturedValue = currentLine(fieldYouWantToRead - 1)
        End While
    End Using

    RichTextBox1.Text = capturedValue
```

Let us know if that is any help.